# How to map excel sheet columns to columns in database?

Tags: java, database, excel

I need to read an excel file and upload the data from the excel sheet to the database.

The excel sheet will have information of users like firstname, lastname, email, age, joining date, country, etc.

I will also have similar User table in the database.

I just need to read each row  from excel sheet and insert into  table.

But for this I need to know which column in excel will go into which column in db tables.

I plan to  do this with the static mapping of column names in table( i.e. property names of user java bean) to the corresponding indexes in the excel sheet.

e.g. lastName maps to index 2 in the excel sheet.

Please help me if this is the right approach?

What is the best possible way of doing this?

Comment: You should probably specify the DB/language (although we can assume it's Java). That said, I think you might find a solution here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaExcel/article.html - you could adapt this to read every row and reorganise this data for insertion into your database with JDBC/Hibernate/whatever

Comment: Also, you could use the first row of input as labels and get the application to enumerate these header values for you on the first iteration. This would mean you wouldn't necessarily have to stick to "lastName maps to index 2" convention provided you give the column the name "lastName", as you could associate a string/label to that index/column in the spreadsheet. There may be a cleaner way of doing this, but it should work and would offer more flexibility than your current solution. Please post an answer to the question above if you  want a proper answer.

Comment: @Aaron Newton. Thanks for the answer. I will be using java and oracle

Comment: @AaronNewton Creating the Excel sheet is not in my my control. Columns may have any headings.

Comment: If the column headings are inconsistent between spreadsheets then using the column index is probably a good way to go. In terms of getting it into the database and good practice for separating your business logic/application/decoupling you could try and use Hibernate http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/firstexample.shtml http://www.javabeat.net/tips/81-batch-insert-in-hibernate.html

Answer (score 0):

THis is alright. You can also have the top row as heading, (if creating the Excel sheet is in your control) to verify the fields. It's pretty straight forward to do this:

1. Use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to read Excel sheet.
2. Add using [JDBC batch insert](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javaentnut_2/index3.html?page=2).

Comment: Creating the Excel sheet is not in my my control. Columns may have any headings

Comment: yeah, then you will have to rely on indexes, and can have have minimal validation like field type checking for sanity purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps for the reading from excel and inserting in to the database.

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

1.its simple API provided by the Apache.
pointo tbe noted .Please make sure the file name and tab name is unique.
2. Also it will be easier to read from the csv file so that it can be inserted  in the database normal control files and you will get the enough support from the oracle.